# Adding true lines from a file to an ArrayList but ignoring false lines

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a program that goes through a maze, and chooses the correct path.  There are multiple levels and rooms. I am able to read in the file and get the program to get through the maze, but the issue is that the program is printing the solution with each room in the file and it should only be printing the correct path.  I am trying to create a loop where the room that are true and can be exited into an ArrayList and ignore the rooms that do not have a way out other than the entrance. Here is an example of a room in the file:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Here is my code, I have put the way I believe should work in a toggle comment towards the bottom:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Maze {
static boolean [][][] maze;
static int dimensions;
static boolean theEnd = false;
static ArrayList<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    String fileName = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What's the name of the file: ");
    fileName = input.nextLine();
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName + ".txt"));

    String firstLine = inputFile.nextLine();
    String [] pieces = firstLine.split(" ");
    dimensions = pieces.length;

    maze = new boolean[dimensions][dimensions][dimensions];
    for(int floor = 0; floor < dimensions; floor++){
        for(int row = 0; row < dimensions; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column < dimensions; column++){
                int place = Integer.parseInt(pieces[column]);
                if(place == 1){
                    maze[floor][row][column] = true;
                }
                else{
                    maze[floor][row][column]= false;
                }
                //System.out.print(place);
            }
            //System.out.println();
            String nextLine = inputFile.nextLine();
            if(!nextLine.isEmpty()){
                pieces = nextLine.split(" ");
            }
            else if (floor != dimensions - 1){
                pieces = inputFile.nextLine().split(" ");
            }
        }
    }

    traverse(0,0,0);
    inputFile.close();
    input.close();
    //System.out.println(theEnd);

}

private static void traverse(int floor, int row, int column) {
    maze[floor][row][column]= false;
    if(floor == dimensions - 1 && row == dimensions - 1 && column == dimensions - 1){
        theEnd = true;
    }

    if(row != 0 && maze[floor][row - 1][column]){
        traverse (floor, row - 1, column);
    }

    if(row != dimensions -1 && maze[floor][row + 1][column]){
        traverse (floor, row + 1, column);
    }

    if(column != 0 && maze[floor][row][column - 1]){
        traverse (floor, row, column - 1);
    }

    if(column != dimensions -1 && maze[floor][row][column + 1]){
        traverse (floor, row, column + 1);
    }

    if(floor != 0 && maze[floor - 1][row][column]){
        traverse (floor - 1, row, column);
    }

    if(floor != dimensions - 1 && maze[floor + 1][row][column]){
        traverse (floor + 1, row, column);
    }

    do{
        System.out.println("(" + floor + ", " + row + ", " + column + ")");
    }while(maze.equals(true));

    // if (the room is true and can be exited){
        // then add the room to the ArrayList
    //}
    // else {
        // the room should be skipped and not added to the ArrayList
    //}
}

}
```

How would I create the if else statement to add the rooms that can be exited into the ArrayList? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's your question? This is not a site that provides code review services.

Comment: @AlexR Thank you for telling me that I forgot to put my question in

Comment: what do you neam by:"    do{
        System.out.println("(" + floor + ", " + row + ", " + column + ")");
    }while(maze.equals(true));" Maze is 3-D array, may be maze[floor][row][column]? You not incrementing anything? Why don't use if instead of while?